# Doing many inserts with entity framework result in => Physical connection is not usable

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I use latest entity framework and insert about 425000 entities via a stored procedure.

Then an exception happens. It still did insert 32766 entities.

**Code**

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    foreach (var item in attributes)
    {
        CreateAttribute(item.productXml, item.NewProduct, context);
    }
}

private static void CreateAttribute(XmlProduct xmlProduct, ProductBase newProdB, MyContext context)
{
    foreach (string attribute in xmlProduct.Properties.Keys)
    {
        double doubleValue;
        if (double.TryParse(xmlProduct.Properties[attribute], out doubleValue))
        {
            //if cast fails
            context.app_sp_AddAttribute(attribute, doubleValue, null, newProdB.ID);
        }
        else
        {
            context.app_sp_AddAttribute(attribute, null, xmlProduct.Properties[attribute], newProdB.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

How can I fix that error?

UPDATE

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> app_sp_AddAttribute(string attributeName, Nullable<double> numericValue, string stringValue, Nullable<int> productID)
{
    var attributeNameParameter = attributeName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("AttributeName", attributeName) :
        new ObjectParameter("AttributeName", typeof(string));

    var numericValueParameter = numericValue.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("NumericValue", numericValue) :
        new ObjectParameter("NumericValue", typeof(double));

    var stringValueParameter = stringValue != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("StringValue", stringValue) :
        new ObjectParameter("StringValue", typeof(string));

    var productIDParameter = productID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ProductID", productID) :
        new ObjectParameter("ProductID", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("app_sp_AddAttribute", attributeNameParameter, numericValueParameter, stringValueParameter, productIDParameter);
}
```

The exception happens at the return statement!

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

Stacktrace:

```
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

{"A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)"}
```

Comment: Does that stored procedure insert/update anything in a column that is a smalint?

Comment: I guess I run into the same problem like this guy: http://wishmesh.com/2013/10/solution-for-a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server/ He has also the magic number 32767 and my 32766 is a typo and should be 32767!

Comment: @rene Not a smallint but an "int".

Comment: Can you afford to call a `context.SaveChanges();` in one of those inner loops? Or start a new context in your inner loop instead of keeping it around for the complete 400K

Comment: With full purpose I want to create the context only ONE time. If I do it 400K times then it works of course but its then 10 min more...

Comment: Is the creation and disposable of the context really the biggest time consumer?

Comment: No but still that error should not happen.

Comment: We agree on that. What is the base class of your `MyContext`?

Comment: I already peeked inside its implementation but I didn't find any uints so far. Need to look a little it further. Does the stacktrace reveal the internal and private methods when it breaks?

Comment: I posted the stacktrace!

Comment: It almost look as this goes dead on the SqlServer and is not client-side related. Can you try a [`SqlConnection.ClearPool(context.Database.Connection);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool(v=vs.110).aspx) every 30000 records or so and see how that works. If that fixes it you have probably hit a bug in the connection pool and that is non-managed code. You'll need to open a support ticket with MS in that case, I'm afraid.

Comment: 32768 is the max size of a smallint.  I am guessing that if you hit that before executing a SaveChanges() even though its not necessary for a procedure you are hitting some limitation.  If you are inserting so many records, why not use a bulk insert? If that is not a possibility maybe just maintain a counter and do a SaveChanges() every 30k records or so?

Answer (score 0):

Based on ewahner's suggestion and doing small research about the cause of the error, it is mostly related to a Sql Server limitation (reading the log from the server might give some hints) and **one possible solution would be to use a bulk insert**. I have used this [extension](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) in a project and the results were very good (dozens of times faster then classic EF save of added entities).

If your stored procedure is complex (does some computations, persists some data in other tables etc.) you can still use Bulk insert:

- generate an identifier (an insert session identifier)
- persist your data via BulkInsert in a session table using the generated identifier as a batch identifier
- call the procedure by providing the identifier as an extra parameter
- remove data from session table (better via a job which runs outside the operational hours, as deletes have great impact on table usage)